# Swift Checklist - Saving the Switch Data for multiple Rows

Tags: swift, uitableview, key-value-observing

So I have a Simple `UITableView` that will display a `UILabel` and a `UISwitch`. I need to be able to get the values of each switch update my object then eventually send the data the API. I has a semi working concept. But this only worked if ALL the cells were visible. Before I only  had 5 items to be checked. So I could simply loop through everything and get the data. Now my checklist has grown to over 20 items.

I understand to a degree why the current code doesn't work. It finds nil values. That would be the cells that aren't visible.

My big question is how do i go about capturing the value of all the cells and the value of all the `UISwitch` values and update my object?

I tried to use the KVO method. This is what I have so far, I have never used this before and a bit lost:

```
private var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?

observation = switchCell.observe(\.switchOne, options: [.old, .new]) { value, change in
    print("value: \(value.switchOne.isOn)")
    print("change old: \(change.oldValue)")
    print("change new: \(change.newValue)")

}
```

My issue is I am not sure what I am supposed to use for the key path. Iget the following warning:

```
Passing reference to non-'@objc dynamic' property 'switchOne' to KVO method 'observe(_:options:changeHandler:)' may lead to unexpected behavior or runtime trap
```

Then the simulator doesn't boot up. What is the easiest way/best way to do this? Like I said I have 2)+ items on my checklist as I completed each item, I turn the switch on. Then I need to get the value for each item, and update the object with the correct value. Then I send the data to the API to store the info to the database. From what I was reading this seemed to be the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store predefined status of switches in array of dictionary like:

```
let alreadyYouHaveThis = [["id": 1, "title": "name"...., ], [ "id": 1, "title": "name"....., ],["id": 1, "title": "name"...., ]

just add one more key in the same data like status...

let updatedData = [["status": true, "id": 1, "title": "name"...., ], ["status": true, "id": 1, "title": "name"....., ],["status": false, "id": 1, "title": "name"...., ]
```

now that status will be used in cellforindexpath method as other:

```
func cellforindexpath() ..... {
let status = data[indexPath.item]["status"]
swithc.tag = indexpath.item
 setswitchstatus on above value
}

and action for switch : 
@Objc func switchStatus(_ switch: UISwitch) {
    let status = data[switch.tag]
    status != status
    data[switch.tag]["status"] = status
....
}
```

or can edit main data source and add these status in that data.

if you cant perform this let me know.

Comment: I guess I am not understanding how this will help. I already have the data and it displays in the `UITableView`. The problem is updating the correct data when a switch is modified. So if the `UISwitch` is offa and I tap it to turn it on. How to I update the right value? I can get it to work if all the cells are displayed. How do I do this if I have to scroll to the last item. The indexPath.row won't line up with correct data set in my array.

Comment: you have some data source for table view and you are using that data to table view and its working already ?? right ?? and every cell showing its own data right ??

now you have two options to handle your switch state/status:

Comment: Those 2 options are?

Comment: for first one updated my answer pls check and 
second one is you can create one array with number of switches you have (its has to be same number as your data soruce ...of course)

and use that array for cellforindexpath().... methond

Comment: This sort of worked. I did have to modify it a bit and tailor it more to using my dataset. But this defiantly put me in the right direction. Again Thanks.